# Add parenthesis around count to separate it from salary amount

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Can we add a dash or parenthesis around the count of jobs to separate it from say a salary:

[image]

Comment: Or maybe it could be "one $130,000 job in Detroit, MI".

Comment: @Gothdo - that looks better.

Comment: @JohH - how about "won $130,000 job in Detroit, MI"?  I like that even more.

Answer (score 1):

We will be revamping those texts in the near future, so right now we will not be doing minor tweaks to them.

Thanks for reporting it!